# How to change the last bit of every pixel in Image and save it as a New Image?

Tags: python, steganography

I am currently working in Steganography Project and I am a beginner.

I developed the following code in Python to complement the Last bit of all pixels and save the Resultant Image as New Image say: `Output.jpg`

Everything in the code works fine until I save the image using `img.save()` function: when I reopen the same image the pixels Remains unchanged.

I am aiming to use Java for this project.

```
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open("P:\Input.jpg")
img=img.convert("RGB")
width,height=img.size
pix=img.load()
for i in range(width):
   for j in range(height):
       r,g,b=pix[i,j]
       bin_b=bin(b)
       bin_list=list(bin_b)
       if bin_list[-1] == 0:
          bin_list[-1]=1
       else:
          bin_list[-1]=0
       b=int("".join(str(i) for i in bin_list),2)
       pix[i,j]=(r,g,b)
img.save("P:\Sampleout.jpg")
```

I need to get modified pixels as either `oldpixels+1` or `oldpixels-1` and not same `oldpixel` in position `i,j`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible problem is that you're using **jpeg** format. This image format is, by default, compressed using a **lossy** compression scheme that is allowed to alter slightly values of the pixel data to get a smaller footprint for the image. There is no guarantee that the lowest bit (or any bit actually) will be the same after saving to jpeg and reloading.

If you want to experiment on this kind of processing you should use lossless formats like BMP, TGA or PNG instead. JPEG also has a [lossless mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG), but it's not used by default by most software.